# Limit Tag Links in Post Content

Tags: custom-taxonomy, tags, template-tags

I am trying to Limit Maximum Numbers of Tag Links to appear within post content. Below is my code. I don't know how to fix it up.

```
function link_words( $text ) {
 $replace_times=3;

    $replace = array();
    $tags = get_tags();

    if ( $tags ) {
        foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
            $replace[ $tag->name, $replace_times ] = sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( get_term_link( $tag ) ), esc_html( $tag->name ) );
        }
    }

    $text = str_replace( array_keys($replace), $replace, $text );
    return $text;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'link_words' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function link_words( $text ) {
$replace = '';
$tags = get_the_tags();
$count=0;
if ( $tags ) {
    foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
        $count++;
        echo $sep . '<a href="'.get_tag_link($tag->term_id).'">'.$tag->name.'</a>';
        $sep = ', ';
          if( $count > 2 ) break;
    }
}
```

}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'link_words', 10, 1 );

Check this.